# 18650 Li Ion Questions

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, bms

Good morning All, I'm obviously a complete novice as far as 18650 and Li-Ion or LiPo batteries is concerned although I do have a reasonable amount of knowledge as far as Electronics design goes, however I have a few questions which I'm hoping someone Wise here can answer.

1. what is the difference between an enhanced BMS and a Protected BMS ?
2. If using unprotected cells (for argument sake we'll say 3s 18650 @2500mAh each can I use a 15 Amp BMS or does it need to match the (3x2500) 7500mAh pack ?
3. Can I use a BMS charger (once again for argument sake well say an Imax B6) to charge a single protected cell ? A Single unprotected cell?

I'm sure these sound like simpleton questions to the "initiated" however before I commit dollars in any significant way to this extension of my endeavours (I currently use NiMh batteries for a number of projects) I'd be extremely grateful for the answers to the questions that have arisen in my thinking But for which Google & Co seem to have NO answers.
Regards,
Leigh

Comment: I’m not sure whether my contributions qualify as an answer but here goes: 1. I wouldn’t assume that ‘enhanced’ or ‘protected’ means anything - read the datasheet.  A BMS for LiPo *should* protect against under- and over-voltage and against excessive current both charging and discharging.  2.  A BMS has to be appropriate for the pack voltage and the expected charge/discharge rates but not necessarily the Ah capacity.  3. I’m not sure what you mean by BMS charger, but a charger that can charge an unprotected cell should be fine for a protected cell.

Comment: Apologies about the BMS charger (bloody thing is on my brain) it should have read Li-Ion/Lipo.

Comment: Thanks for your response Frog.      I note also that a number of the BMS's have multiple take off points (3.7, 7.4, 11.1 V etc.) does this mean that you Could charge 1 or 1s, 2 or 2s (or 2s x X parallel) or 3 or 3s (or 3s x X parallel) depending on what/where you connected them and provided you don't exceed the BMS max Amperage?

Comment: almost certainly not - these BMS allow for charge balancing for series cells, which is a good thing.  For NiMH you can trickle charge indefinitely and so the whole pack will charge fully eventually, but with LiPo it’s important not to overcharge, so the BMS will bypass the first cells to reach max voltage and allow the others to catch up.

Comment: Thanks again Frog . (Oh Gawd I feel like the dumbest kid in the classroom [again], NiMh was so much easier for a knucklehead to grasp, I'm begining to get the feeling I'd better hunt around for some mighty good insurance on the Lab/Workspace if I continue my current obsession with Li Ion/LiPo)

Comment: Unless you’re using individual cells, any packs you buy certainly ought to include protection circuitry.  I’ve just had to deal with a battery fire and it wasn’t pretty.

Comment: Thank you Frog, that makes me feel SO MUCH safer ( NOT!!), The battery/packs are for  different projects & will require differing Voltages, the "Projects" are an unfortunate & weird collection  of "Stuff", which because of my knowledge in an (uselessly) lge number of areas I've been "volunteered" for. They're for the local High (Secondary) school which has around 350 kids but we're in the country (rural) & an "Independent" Federal & State region it gets very little money, so if the kids need something or to learn something it's generally the local community that picks up the slack

Comment: Knowing which experiments to carry out in private (the first time anyway) is the foundation of wisdom